# URL alias for File field on a Content Type

Tags: files, path-aliases

I have a File field on one of my content types and I'd like a URL alias for downloading that file regardless of how many times the actual uploaded file has been updated. Any advice?

I've been looking into the [Attachment Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/attachment_links) module as it accurately describes what I want to do, but it seems it isn't actively being maintained. Is there a community best practice for this type of functionality before I run with Attachment Links?

Comment: If the module solves your problem I wouldn't be concerned that it hasn't had a commit in some time as it has a 7.x stable release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well [attachment links module](https://www.drupal.org/project/attachment_links) does exactly what you want, this module is still being maintained, the fact is that there is not a new stable release for this module, but the manteiners are solving issues in the issues queue, and they commit changes to the 7.x-1.x-dev download that version and you will see it works like a charm. Check also [Upload replace module](http://drupal.org/project/upload_replace) is good also use the 7.x-1.x-dev version of this module. Both modules are for the same purpose but they do it in a different way.

Comment: I used upload replace module, patch needed: https://www.drupal.org/node/1115484#comment-11329669, works perfect! thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you install/enable the [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module, it integrates with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto).  If you set a pattern like `file/[file:fid]`, then you should have a permanent URL.

Just keep in mind that File Entity can introduce some subtle changes with how files are handled, particularly with field formatters.

Comment: Hey MPD, this is a great suggestion! we will investigate.